# Datetime update goes wrong when using Bootstrap-Editable

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime, x-editable

I'm trying to update a sql datetime. I just wana update the time and have some scripts for substr(). Now when i update the Hrs and min the day (d) get's reset to 1 in the first edit and 0 in a second edit.

I'm using a html table generated by php and bootstrap-editable for editing the rows using Js and PHP.

Why does the date return first 01 and then 00 in db?

Ex. 2012-02-23 00:00:00 becomes 2012-02-01 00:00:00 in first update.

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' id='".$row['id']."' class='usr_stamp_out' data-name='usr_stamp_out' data-type='text' data-pk='".$row['id']."' data-url='php/time.php' data-title='Stämpla ut..'>".substr($row['usr_stamp_out'],11,5)."</a>
```

**PHP**

```
$id = $_POST['pk'];
$updated_usr_stamp_out = $_POST['value'];

if($row){
    //Substring datetime to 0000-00-00
    $usr_stamp_out_date = substr($row['usr_stamp_out'],0,9);

    //Add old date to updated time
    $new_usr_stamp_out = $usr_stamp_out_date." ".$updated_usr_stamp_out;

    //Prepare query
    $query = "UPDATE table SET usr_stamp_out = :usr_stamp_out WHERE id = :id";

    // Security measures
    $query_params = array(':id' => $id,':usr_stamp_out' => $new_usr_stamp_out);

    //Connect and execute
    try {  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$usr_stamp_out_date = substr($row['usr_stamp_out'],0,9);` is only getting the first nine characters of the date instead of the ten needed to have the correct date.

```
$usr_stamp_out_date = substr($row['usr_stamp_out'],0,10);
```

A alternative way to do this is to just get the date using PHP's date functionality:

```
$usr_stamp_out_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['usr_stamp_out']));
```

Comment: Perfect! I hate "datetime" and all it´s format and converting! I use your second example. Thank you!